# luatex prevent creation of \endash, \emdash ligatures in \url

Tags: luatex, url

I want to let `\url` breaks on hyphens '-'. url package has `hyphens` option but if there are several hyphens in url luatex turnes them to ligatures and latex doesn't.
I can't find how to suppress "--", "---" ligatures creation in url using normal font.
I tried to edit `\UrlBreaks, \UrlOrds, \verbatim@nolig@list` by adding/removing `\do\-` but then I get other *buggy* results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

% \def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
  % \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\&\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#%
  % \do\- % tried to add it here
  % }

% original macro from url has two `\do\-`. Why?
% \def\UrlOrds{\do\*
  % \do\-
  % \do\~\do\'\do\"
  % \do\-
  % }%

% it seems that this should do the trick, but it does'nt?
%\makeatletter
%\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'\do\-}
%\makeatother
  
\def\UrlFont{}%\ttfamily}

\fboxsep=0pt
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\par\url{-}
\par\url{--}
\par\url{---}

\fbox{\parbox[t]{3cm}{
\par\url{11111111111111-aaaaaaaa}
\par\url{11111111111111--aaaaaaa}
\par\url{11111111111111---aaaaaa}
}}

\end{document}
```

latex output:

[image]

lualatex output:

[image]

I use TL2019 and **dvilualatex** (dvi mode is a requirement)

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with lualatex.

Comment: “dvi mode is a requirement” Why?

Comment: Does -{}-{}- help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. I made `-` an active character which inserts math character and `\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty`. Now luatex doesn't creates ndash/mdash and breaks links on `-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
  
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \appto\UrlSpecials{\do\-{\mathchar 0045\penalty \UrlBreakPenalty}}%
  }
 
\def\UrlFont{}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\par\url{-}
\par\url{--}
\par\url{---}

\fbox{\parbox[t]{3cm}{
\par\url{11111111111111-aaaaaaaa}
\par\url{11111111111111--aaaaaaa}
\par\url{11111111111111---aaaaaa}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]